# PHP/HTML Not aligning

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I've decided to go back to trying to learn PHP and I've created this sort of thing before and I thought it had been a while so I decided to try and make another one. I'm trying to make a database table/page. But the data isn't aligning right in the table. Here is what it looks like
https://prnt.sc/1qcrdo8
Below is my code:

index.php

```
<?php 
main();
function main() {

include('index.html');
require('../Content/dbconnect.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM Orders";
  $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if ($count>0) {

     while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
     echo "<table class='content'>";
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . "</td><td>" . $row[2] . "</td><td>" . $row[3] . "</td></tr>";
     echo "</table>";
  }

  }
}
```

and my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Style.css">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <table>
  <div class="content">
    <table id="content" class="content">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>CustomerName</th>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Customer Address</th>
            <th>Problems Described</th>
            <th>Notes for the customer</th>
        </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use CSS to set the alignment

Comment: When you say aligning right, do you mean you want the text to align right? Or to align correctly? And if correctly, what is correct in this case? Also, that is a helluvan address.

Comment: @ADyson yeah I did try that hence why the echoed text was in the middle it just wasn't aligning into the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove your table tag from the loop. --  Also it helps to put table headers in to identify your columns.   With your code as-is .. It's creating a new table every loop iteration .. Making the table data mis-align. You need to create the table ONCE .. Create the headers ONCE ..  Loop through and generate your `<tr>` `</tr>`  --  And close your table ONCE ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Style.css">
    <title>Admin Panel</title>

</head>
<body>


<!--  I am commenting this out, because we echo it below in php.  
You can remove that echo, and uncomment this for the same result

<table id="content" class="content">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>CustomerName</th>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Customer Address</th>
        <th>Problems Described</th>
        <th>Notes for the customer</th>
    </tr>

-->

<?php
require('../Content/dbconnect.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM Orders";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count>0) {

   echo "<table class='content'>";
   echo "<tr><th>Row 0 header</th>
             <th>Row 1 header</th>
             <th>Row 2 header</th>
             <th>Row 3 header</th>
         </tr>";

   while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {       
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row[1] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row[2] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row[3] . "</td>
            </tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that has worked, I don't need the index.html BUT I do need to add CSS to the table rows but it doesn't seem to let me other than the table data

Comment: I edited my answer for you .. You can move in and out of html easily within a `php` file ..   It should get you started anyway.